# Trouble backing up rom on locked proprietary mediatek device - mt8163 chipset

Tags: firmware, firmware-analysis, flash, rom

I have a proprietary tablet with mediatek chipset MT8163v, and getting the factory ROM and/or scatter file is out of the question. My goal is to flash with TWRP.

The device has a custom android repo that doesn't allow me to install apps or anything of that nature, so I can't go that route.

I'm trying to do a readback of the preloader partition with spflash tool, then use WwR to generate the scatter. The details of how this works can be found [here](https://forum.hovatek.com/thread-21970.html). It's pretty simple.

When I attempt the readback, I'm getting this error:

```
s_dl_get_dram_setting_fail(5054)
```

Everything I've read indicates that this is due to an incorrect scatter file. However, just to be safe, I used a secure boot bypass found [here](https://github.com/MTK-bypass/bypass_utility) just to make certain that secure boot isn't the problem. With the bypass however, I get the same error.

From everything I've read, a readback is the *one thing* I should be able to do without the factory rom/scatter files. Which is why I'm perplexed as to why I'm getting this error when doing a simple readback.

I've even payed the tech guys at Hovatek (who were very helpful) to help work on this. We tried the newest Infinity Box with dongle as well, to no avail.

Here is the partition info in the scatter generated by WwR:

```
- partition_index: SYS0
partition_name: PRELOADER
file_name: preloader.bin
is_download: true
type: SV5_BL_BIN
linear_start_addr: 0x0
physical_start_addr: 0x0
partition_size: 0x80000
region: EMMC_BOOT_1
storage: HW_STORAGE_EMMC
boundary_check: true
is_reserved: false
operation_type: BOOTLOADERS
reserve: 0x00
```

Seems to me the only variable properties are `physical_start_addr` and `partition_size`. However, it seems that when I look at scatter files for other mediatek chipsets, it's always either `0x80000` or `0x40000`. And from what I've read this shouldn't matter just doing a readback. But I've tried both to no avail.

Does anyone know anything else I could try?? I'm even willing to try ROMs from other devices with the same chipset. At this point I don't care if I brick it.